# Vertex deletion in knotless and linkless graphs

Tags: graph-theory, knot-theory

If $G$ is a graph and $G-v$ is linkless for some vertex $v$, is $G$ necessarily knotless?

Of course, one can assume that $v$ is adjacent to every vertex in $G-v$.

Here, a graph is *linkless* if it has an embedding in 3-space with no two linked cycles. And a graph is *knotless* if it has an embedding in 3-space such that every cycle is an unknot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, this is false.

Your question was posed by Adams in 1994, and was disproved by [Foisy](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.10114/abstract) in 2003.